# PHP Looping through a FOREACH loop

Tags: php

I have a FOREACH loop which is not picking up the first element in the array.

I have a submit form which has the following:

```
<input name="repaired[<?php echo $row_Faults['UniqueID']; ?>]" type="checkbox" id="repaired" value="1" class="required"/>
```

If I echo the $_POST['repair'] array I see two records but when the code is run the first record is not been processed.

```
foreach($_POST['repaired'] as $uniqueID => $repairedValue){   

$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE ".$Hist." SET Status=%s, LettoStatus=%s WHERE UniqueID= '".$_POST["UniqueID"]."'",
 GetSQLValueString($_POST['Status'] = $StatusCode , "int"),
GetSQLValueString($_POST['LettoStatus'] = $LettoCode , "int"));

mysql_select_db($database_iMaint, $iMaint);
$Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $iMaint) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: **Don't**. **Ever**. **Use**. `mysql_*`.

Comment: Although not directly related to your question I highly recommend sanitizing your inputs. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php

Comment: @kennethPhough thanks for your input, once I get this foreach loop working I will then look at the sanitizing. Thanks

Comment: You have `$uniqueID` var in your foreach but in your `$updateSQL` you still use `$_POST["UniqueID"]`.

Comment: @Vitalii Strimbanu I naver spotted that, many thanks for your time.
RESOLVED

Comment: Now try to get rid of `mysql_*`

Comment: @Vitalii Strimbanu will do.

Comment: @Jose Manuel Abarca Rodríguez He should, I am waiting for hime to do so.

Comment: Are schools still teaching these deprecated and also dangerous MySQL functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `$uniqueID` variable initialized in your foreach but in your $updateSQL you still use `$_POST["UniqueID"]`
So all you need is to change your `$updateSQL`

```
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE ".$Hist." SET Status=%s, LettoStatus=%s WHERE
    UniqueID= '".$uniqueID."'",    
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['Status'] = $StatusCode , "int"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['LettoStatus'] = $LettoCode , "int"));
```